# Unable to unmarshal shadow class variable in jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-serialization, unmarshalling

```
@XmlSeeAlso(Employee.class)
public abstract class Person {
     protected String name;

     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee extends Person {
     private String name;

     public String getName() {
        return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }
}
```

and in my public static main(), i setName("John") and marshal it to an xml.

This generates an XML :-

```
<Employee>
     <name>John</John>
</Employee>
```

However, when i unmarshal this to the Employee object, neither the super nor local class had their name variable initialized to 'John'. I suspect its the sharing of the same name variable for both the inherited and parent class. I understand that this is bad practice, however how can one unmarshal to the Employee class? or Both?

Thank u.

Comment: What get/set methods do you have for the `name` field and how are they annotated?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan i edited to show the getter and setters. They have no annotations and they return the local class name var.

Comment: Any insights to this issue? I am encountering the same problem... and I cannot change any of the variable names!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this question starts from basic java principal. Since derived class override setName and getName . (new Employee()).setName("John") populates Employee's name not Person's. So if you want to populate properties of both the classes you should change person class to

```
@XmlSeeAlso(Employee.class)
public abstract class Person {
     protected String firstName;

     public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
     }

     public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
     this.firstName = firstName;
     }
}
```

and do marshal of this.

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.setName("John");
e.setLastName("JohnLast");
```

then your xml will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<employee>
    <lastName>JohnLast</lastName>
    <name>John</name>
</employee>
```

and xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="employee" type="employee"/>

  <xs:complexType name="employee">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="person">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="person" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and during unmarshalling following works and name and lastName gets populated,

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
Employee e = (Employee) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
Person p = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
```