# Illegal XML/exception un/marshalling shadow variable in JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following problem: I have some code (that I cannot change) where one variable of a parent class gets shadowed by a variable of a child class. When annotated as `@XmlAttribute` and marshalled with JAXB this results in illegal XML and when unmarshalled it results in an exception (due to illegal XML). Here is a minimal example, showing the problem:

```
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.PrintStream;

    import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
    import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
    import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler;

    import org.junit.Test;

    public class InheritanceJaxbTest {

        @Test
        public void testInheritanceField() {
            B b = new B("value");
            String xml = toXML(b);
            System.out.println(xml);
            B b_out = fromXML(xml);
            System.out.println(b_out.myField);
        }

        @XmlRootElement
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        private static class A {

            public A() {
            }

            public A(String myField) {
                this.myField = myField;
            }

            @XmlAttribute
            private String myField;
        }

        @XmlRootElement
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        private static class B extends A {

            public B() {
                super();
            }

            public B(String myField) {
                super(myField);
                this.myField = myField;
            }

            @XmlAttribute
            private String myField;
        }

        public <T> T fromXML(String xml) {
            try {
                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class, B.class);
                Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
                unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new DefaultValidationEventHandler());
                return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exc);
            }
        }

        public String toXML(Object obj) {
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
                JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class, B.class);
                Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
                marshaller.setEventHandler(new DefaultValidationEventHandler());
                marshaller.marshal(obj, ps);
                return baos.toString();
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exc);
            }
        }
    }
```

This produces the following (obviously illegal) XML:

```
<b myField="value" myField="value"/>
```

And the subsequent unmarshalling operation throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "myField" was already specified for element "b".]
at InheritanceJaxbTest.fromXML(InheritanceJaxbTest.java:67)
```

Since I basically cannot change the underlying Java classes, I want to solve this problem with some kind of XmlAdapter or custom XmlStreamWriter or something similar. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467116/unable-to-unmarhsal-shadow-class-variable-in-jaxb) is related but gives nonetheless no insights how to proceed without changing the Java classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd address this by writing a custom [annotation reader](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/8199de1117c4fae042af2eeca473f7b5994a36eb/jaxb-ri/core/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/annotation/AnnotationReader.java). Annotation reader is basically the thing which reads annotations for classes. So you can implement your own reader which handles the shadowed field case as you want it.

```
public interface AnnotationReader<T,C,F,M> {

// ...

    /**
     * Reads an annotation on a property that consists of a field.
     */
    <A extends Annotation> A getFieldAnnotation(Class<A> annotation,
                                                F field, Locatable srcpos);

    /**
     * Checks if the given field has an annotation.
     */
    boolean hasFieldAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType, F field);

// ...

    /**
     * Gets all the annotations on a field.
     */
    Annotation[] getAllFieldAnnotations(F field, Locatable srcPos);

// ...

}
```

You can then use your reader when creating the JAXB context:

```
final AnnotationReader<Type, Class, Field, Method> annotationReader = new MyCustomAnnotationReader();

final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

properties.put(JAXBRIContext.ANNOTATION_READER, annotationReader);
```

Alternatively consider using [MOXy XML bindings](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/runtime003.htm) instead of annotations.